# Error during Execution of File Upload

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, web

During the execution of project at the Image upload time, Browser is displaying this error.
I am using SQl Server as Database.

```
`Server Error in '/' Application.
Maximum request length exceeded.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 
[HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() +9803702
   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() +63
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +160
   System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm() +69
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +13
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() +9800635
   System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) +95
   System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +69
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +220
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1073.0`
```

Is there any restriction limit During file Upload for SQl Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is raised by your web server and not by SQL server.

If you are using IIS, you can modify your web.config to allow large file uploads.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxxxxx" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For IIS version 7 and above, use the following..

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="xxxxxxx" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

The above example is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Also, please read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net).

Comment: Why dint you gave the link to original answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded

Comment: sorry..i should have..i used multiple sources to get the right syntax to be shown on the config file. I have modifed my answer

Comment: Plagiarism is not advised. If you knew the source then please attribute it. You could have commented the same